# Can the phrase にまた_が戻ってくるんだ have multiple meanings?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This is script from a game where 2 characters are talking to each other. One says:

> 「賞金が出たら馬を買おう
> セボック村にまた馬が戻ってくるんだ
> 徴集兵のバイトなんかオサラバだぜ

Here is the NTSC-U version:

> With a reward, I'll get a horse
> and return to T'Bok Village.
> It'll end my mercenary work.

I don't understand what また馬が戻ってくるんだ means exactly. Maybe, "Horses are making a comeback in T'Bok Village." or "Horses are becoming popular once again in T'Bok Village."?

Answer (score 2):

### The text and translation

I'm not sure what NTSC-U is, and we don't have a lot of context, but their translation seems a bit off.

Let's treat each line as a separate statement.

> 賞金が出たら馬を買おう

Breaking that down word by word:

> [賞金]{Reward   }[が]{[SUBJ]   }[出たら]{if/when comes out   }[馬]{horse   }[を]{[OBJ]   }[買おう]{maybe/will buy}

"With a reward, I'll get a horse" → Close enough, I guess.

> セボック村にまた馬が戻ってくるんだ

→

> [セボック]{T'Bok   }[村]{village   }[に]{to   }[また]{again   }[馬]{horse   }[が]{[SUBJ]   }[戻ってくる]{return / come back   }[んだ]{[EXPLANATORY]}

"and return to T'Bok Village." → Given the grammar of the previous line ending in 買おう, this next line must be a separate statement: "[Horses in general / this horse in specific] will come back again to T'Bok Village."

> 徴集兵のバイトなんかオサラバだぜ

→

> [徴集兵]{conscript soldier / draftee   }[の]{[POSSESSIVE]   }[バイト]{part-time job   }[なんか]{kind of thing   }[オサラバ]{farewell   }[だ]{[PREDICATE]   }[ぜ]{[EMPHATIC]}

### Your specific question

> Can the phrase にまた_が戻ってくるんだ have multiple meanings?

I suspect there's some confusion here.  I hope the breakdown above helps explain the overall structure better.

Regarding two specific things in your question:

- The に applies to the preceding noun, and in this context it's basically "to [the village]".
- The また is just "again".  Here, it emphasizes the sense of "returning" expressed by the verb phrase 戻ってくる.

---

Please comment if the above does not address your question.

Comment: @ Eiríkr Útlendi Thanks for the reply! You're answer is very detailed and informative.

Comment: @SomaRise, cheers!  Just realized I had a brain-fart about the に, that applies to the preceding **noun**.  Just fixed the post.  :)